# MongoDB: $lookup before $match. Is there performance issue?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 2 Collections:

Users:

```
{
_id: "unique_user_id",
name: "developer"
}
```

Reports:

```
{
_id: "unique_report_id",
createdBy: "unique_user_id"
}
```

**The requirement that I have got**:
extract all reports that created by the `user` with the name `developer` and it will be *preferable* to do this in the scope of one request to Mongo DB, the query that was implemented by me:

```
db.getCollection('reports').aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$lookup" : {
                      from: "users",
                      localField: "createdBy",
                      foreignField: "_id",
                      as: "user"
                      }

        },
        {"$unwind": "$user"},
        
        {"$addFields": {"createdBy": "$user.email"}},
        
        {"$match": {"createdBy": "developer"}}
   ]
);
```

On the local machine, it works fine, but I think about the `PROD` environment, where thousands `Reports` documents already stored:

My query executes `$lookup` operation against all Documents that available in Collection and only after that applies `$match` operation and I am afraid that in this case, it is a huge performance issue.

could you please confirm or reject my fears?
or provide alternative examples?

Comment: Did you try aggregating on 'Users' collection, then matching, then lookup and adding your new Fields? I am unaware of the final result structure you're trying to achieve so can't be sure. That would be better performance wise.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your lookup stage as:

```
{
"$lookup": {
  "from": "users",
  "pipeline":[{$match:{
      "createdBy":"developer"
  }}],
  "as":"user"
}
```

This will bring in memory only the matching documents. It will help if the "createdBy" field is indexed. After that, use $project to get only the fields you need.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need only `developer`, first you reduce the number of documents passed to the next stage by applying `match` at the beginning.

Currently you are passing all the documents in your collection to all of your stages. It will impact performance for sure.

1. Use users collection in aggregate
2. Match by email with developer
3. Then add lookup with reports collection

Or

1. Filter developer reports from reports collection
2. Lookup with users collection

You can avoid `unwind`, `addFields` by this if you dont need flattened output structure.